# Como fazer o DbUnit reconhecer o tipo de dado POLYGON do Postgresql?

Tags: java, testes, dbunit, postgresql

Tenho o seguinte domínio do tipo `polygon` no banco de dados:

```
CREATE DOMAIN "global".polygon AS pg_catalog.polygon;
```

A seguinte tabela que utiliza esse domínio:

```
CREATE TABLE user.area_geom
(
  id_area_geom serial NOT NULL,
  polygon global.polygon
);
```

E a seguinte classe que extende `DBTestCase` configurando o dataset antes dos testes serem executados:

```
public abstract class MyDBTestCase extends DBTestCase {

public MyDBTestCase () {
    // Configura url, user, password e driver do banco de dados.
}

@Override
protected IDataSet getDataSet() throws Exception {
    // Meu arquivo .xml com os dados de teste.
    return new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder()
            .build(new FileInputStream(MyTestDB.FLAT_XML_DATASET));
}

@Override
protected void setUpDatabaseConfig(DatabaseConfig config) {

    /* Habilita case sensitive para os nomes de tabelas do banco */
    config.setProperty(DatabaseConfig.FEATURE_CASE_SENSITIVE_TABLE_NAMES,
            true);

    /* Habilita a utilização de fully qualified names para tabelas */
    config.setProperty(DatabaseConfig.FEATURE_QUALIFIED_TABLE_NAMES, true);

    /* Configura o tipo de dado para o PostgreSQL */
    config.setProperty(DatabaseConfig.PROPERTY_DATATYPE_FACTORY,
            new PostgresqlDataTypeFactory());
}
}
```

Esse setup funciona perfeitamente para todos os tipos de dados normalmente utilizados, mas quando eu mapeei a tabela `area_geom` que contém um domínio do tipo `polygon`, o console começou a gerar a seguinte saída:

`9081 [main] WARN org.dbunit.util.SQLHelper - area_geom.polygon data type (1111, 'polygon') not recognized and will be ignored. See FAQ for more information.`

No [FAQ](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/faq.html#typenotrecognized) proposto pela mensagem de erro, não há nada que me indique como implementar um tipo de dado "personalizado" em cima de um data type já existente, tampouco fazer o DbUnit reconhecer meu `polygon`, já gastei algumas horas de Google e não encontrei nada.

Alguém tem alguma luz para esse problema?

Comment: Você já experimentou usar o [PostGIS](http://postgis.org/)?

Comment: Peter, eu já utilizo o PostGIS a nível de database, porém nenhum jar em meu projeto. A implementação para o reconhecimento de data types do PostGIS também pode ser feita de acordo com a resposta do elias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O item interessante na FAQ é este: [How to replace the default data type factory?](http://www.dbunit.org/faq.html#typefactory), que explica como configurar uma *custom data type factory* pro DBunit -- basicamente, uma classe que implemente [IDataTypeFactory](http://www.dbunit.org/apidocs/org/dbunit/dataset/datatype/IDataTypeFactory.html).

Você terá que adicionar um [DataType](http://www.dbunit.org/xref/org/dbunit/dataset/datatype/DataType.html) para Polygon (pode se inspirar no [IntervalType](http://www.dbunit.org/xref/org/dbunit/ext/postgresql/IntervalType.html)), ficando algo assim:

```java
public class PolygonType extends AbstractDataType {
      public PolygonType() {
          super("polygon", Types.OTHER, String.class, false);
      }
      /* ... implemente aqui getSqlValue(..) e setSqlValue(..) para o tipo POLYGON */
}
```

Depois criar uma classe estendendo a [PostgresqlDataTypeFactory](http://www.dbunit.org/apidocs/org/dbunit/ext/postgresql/PostgresqlDataTypeFactory.html) ([código aqui](http://www.dbunit.org/xref/org/dbunit/ext/postgresql/PostgresqlDataTypeFactory.html)) que implemente a lógica especial para o tipo `POLYGON` e delegue para os demais tipos, algo tipo:

```java
public class PolygonPostgresDataFactory extends PostgresqlDataTypeFactory {
    public DataType createDataType(int sqlType, String sqlTypeName)
                                         throws DataTypeException {
        logger.debug("createDataType(sqlType={}, sqlTypeName={})",
                       String.valueOf(sqlType), sqlTypeName);
        if (sqlType == Types.OTHER && "polygon".equals(sqlTypeName))
             return new PolygonType();
        }      
        return super.createDataType(sqlType, sqlTypeName);
    }
}
```

Finalmente, você altera ali no seu método `MyDBTestCase::setUpDatabaseConfig` para usar a DataTypeFactory customizada:

```java
/* Configura o tipo de dado para o PostgreSQL */
config.setProperty(DatabaseConfig.PROPERTY_DATATYPE_FACTORY,
                           new PostgresqlDataTypeFactory());
```

Comment: Perfeito Elias, implementei como proposto e o tipo POLYGON passou a ser reconhecido. Agradeço muito sua ajuda!

Comment: Show de bola, Bruno! Valeu pela edição. =)